Detectar palabras y agruparlas en enlaces
Tengo un texto que lleva intercalado unos códigos entre etiquetas :
$texto = "Esto es un texto,<span class=\"sg\">H7225</span> que<span class=\"sg\">H1254</span> debería,<span class=\"sg\">H430</span> estar enlazado<span class=\"sg\">H8064</span> por grupos de palabras<span class=\"sg\">H776</span>.";

Cada palabra o grupo de palabras pertenecen al código que les sigue, por lo tanto necesito agrupar esa palabra o palabras en un enlace cada vez que el sistema detecta que hay un código. Por ejemplo, "Esto es un texto" debería ir enlazado en un único enlace porque pertenece al código H7225; "que" debería ir enlazado solo porque pertenece al H1254, etc.
Eso lo consigo con este código, pero lo que no consigo es mostrar los signos de puntuación correctamente.
Los signos de puntuación y los espacios en blanco no deben ir enlazados. Y los códigos deben estar ocultos.
¿Qué me falta para lograrlo?
<?php

$texto = "Es es un texto,<span class=\"sg\">H7225</span> que<span class=\"sg\">H1254</span> debería,<span class=\"sg\">H430</span> estar enlazado<span class=\"sg\">H8064</span> por grupos de palabras<span class=\"sg\">H776</span>.";

// Encontrar todos los grupos de palabras y códigos
preg_match_all('/(?:<span class="sg">(.*?)<\/span>|[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+)*)/u', $texto, $matches);

// Encontrar todos los signos de puntuación que no están dentro de etiquetas HTML

// $matches[0] contiene todos los grupos de palabras y códigos
$words_and_code = $matches[0];

// Variable para almacenar el texto con enlaces y códigos ocultos
$final_text = "";

// Recorrer cada elemento
foreach ($words_and_code as $word_or_code) {
    // Verificar si el elemento es una palabra o un código
    if (preg_match('/<span class="sg">(.*?)<\/span>/', $word_or_code, $match)) {
        // Si es un código, ocultarlo utilizando etiquetas span y CSS
        $final_text .= "<span style='display: none;'>{$match[1]}</span>";
    } else {
        // Si es una palabra, agregarla al texto con enlaces
        $final_text .= "<a class='word-link sub word-i' data-verse-id='$verse_id' href='#'>$word_or_code</a>";
        $final_text .= htmlspecialchars($word_or_code);
    } 
}


// Imprimir el texto del versículo resultante
echo "<p>$final_text";

?>

El resultado debería ser:
[Esto es un texto][1], [que][1] [debería][1], [estar enlazado][1] [por grupos de palabras][1].

Como se puede observar, se enlazan los grupos de palabras y los signos de puntuación se colocan en su sitio pero sin enlace.

Ayudaría si colocas el string correcto que debe imprimir el código

He actualizado la pregunta mostrando cómo debería visualizarse. Gracias!

@Jok ¿No sería lo mismo que, borrar los <span> y después separar la cadena por ,|. ?

Podría ser. Quien dice ,y .dice todos los signos de puntuación. Mi problema es que no controlo bien el regex.

@Jok, si los caracteres de puntuación no serían un problema, pero básicamente sería eso, no? Basándome en "El resultado" no veo que haya nada más o si? PD: Cuando hay más de un usuario comentando tenes que usar @[USER] para que el mensaje le llegue al usuario a quien estás respondiendo.

Si dentro de los <span>###</span> solo hay códigos, qué tal si capturas el texto en un grupo y los códigos en otro grupo del regex, así:
<?php

$texto = "Es es un texto,<span class=\"sg\">H7225</span> que<span class=\"sg\">H1254</span> debería,<span class=\"sg\">H430</span> estar enlazado<span class=\"sg\">H8064</span> por grupos de palabras<span class=\"sg\">H776</span>.";

preg_match_all('/(.+?)<span.*?>(.+?)<\/span>/', $texto, $matches);
$res = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);

El array $res tendrá lo siguiente:
array (
  'H7225' => 'Es es un texto,',
  'H1254' => ' que',
  'H430' => ' debería,',
  'H8064' => ' estar enlazado',
  'H776' => ' por grupos de palabras',
)

El resto es recorrer ese array con un for e ir procesando los valores para eliminar espacios no deseados y etiquetar los valores vinculándolos con las llaves.

Como las líneas terminan siempre en un punto, este se puede agregar manualmente en el procesado. Si hubiesen otras cosas (incluyendo el punto), se puediera capturar el final de la línea para luego concatenarla con el texto procesado:
preg_match('/.+<\/span>(.*)$/', $texto, $match);
$end_of_line = $match[1];

Con esos conceptos se puede escribir un código, como lo siguiente. Notar que dentro del for se verifica si el último caracter es un caracter alfa, si es otra cosa, se separa del texto para que no forme parte del etiquetado, y se agrega posteriormente.
[ NOTA ] La parte del ctype_alpha no funcionará bien si una palabra termina con tílde. Entonces es posible que debas crear una función más compleja que evalúe esas posibilidades.
<?php

$texto = "Es es un texto,<span class=\"sg\">H7225</span> que<span class=\"sg\">H1254</span> debería,<span class=\"sg\">H430</span> estar enlazado<span class=\"sg\">H8064</span> por grupos de palabras<span class=\"sg\">H776</span>.";

preg_match_all('/(.+?)<span.*?>(.+?)<\/span>/', $texto, $matches);
$res = array_combine($matches[2], $matches[1]);

preg_match('/.+<\/span>(.*)$/', $texto, $match);
$end_of_line = $match[1];

$resp = [];
foreach($res as $cod=>$str) {
    $phr = trim($str);
    $str1 = mb_substr($phr, 0, -1);
    $str2 = mb_substr($phr, -1);
    if(ctype_alpha($str2)) {
        $str1 = $phr;
        $str2 = '';
    }
    $resp[] = "[$str1][$cod]$str2";
}
$result = implode(' ', $resp) . $end_of_line;

Y la variable $result tendrá:
[Es es un texto][H7225], [que][H1254] [debería][H430], [estar enlazado][H8064] [por grupos de palabras][H776].

Si necesitas que sea [1] en vez de [código], colocar $resp[] = "[$str1][1]$str2";

Está bien, lo he probado. Sin embargo, falta algo más, al final de la frase (en este caso) hay un signo de puntuación que es un punto y el array no lo muestra. ¿De qué manera se puede sacar? Gracias!

El . no posee el <span> correspondiente a continuación que es la condición de la regex de la respuesta. Cual debería ser el key en este caso para ese elemento de array ? ???? => '.'

@cachique @jok bueno, el . es el fin de la línea y digo que siempre debería ir, por lo que se puede adicionar vía el script al terminar de procesar esa línea. Si hay otras cosas, que no son un . sería algo más difícil de parsear de esta manera. Se me puede ocurrir que se busque el primer </span>, de derecha a izquierda, y se haga un substr() de esa parte para adicionarlo al final del resultado.
